# Text with /n matching in regex and Openrefine

Tags: regex, excel, openrefine

I'm trying to filter a text that has `new lines` in open refine.

The input is:

```
Them Spanish girls love me like I'm Aventura
I'm the man, y'all don't get it, do ya?
Type of money, everybody acting like they knew ya
Go Uptown, New York City, bitch
Them Spanish girls love me like I'm Aventura
Tell Uncle Luke I'm out in Miami, too
Them Spanish girls love me like I'm Aventura
```

The expected Result would be:

```
Type of money, everybody acting like they knew ya
Go Uptown, New York City, bitch
Them Spanish girls love me like I'm Aventura
```

I'm trying to get the line with the keyword and the lines before and after.

My code to do it with standard regex looks like that:

`/((.*\n){2})^.*\b(New York)\b.*((.*\n){3})/m`

But that doesn't work in open refine.
I tried the following, but it only returns 'null'

`value.match(/.*(\New York)/.*)`

Any one has an idea how I could do it?
I really need to keep the lines, so I cant do a
`replace(/\n/,'')` before the match.

Comment: Could it be that the `newline` is a `<cr><lf>` sequence and you need `\r\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brand new [OpenRefine 3](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/releases/tag/3.0-beta) has a [`find()` function](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#openrefine-30-onwards--findstring-s-regexp-p) much more user friendly than `match()`.

I think this regex should do the trick :

```
value.find(/(.*\n){1}.+New York.+(\n.*){1}/).join('\n')
```

Result:

[image]

If for some reason you prefer to stay in OpenRefine 2.8, Python/Jython offers an alternative:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r".+?\n.+New York.+\n.+", value)
return "\n".join(matches)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How would I need to change it, to get 2 lines before and after?

Comment: Ok, I got it with `value.find(/(.*\n){2}.+New York.+(\n.*){2}/).join('\n')`. Thanks!

Comment: I found a small bug in the regex. It doesn't match if the searched word is just before a new line. `.+` doesn't match new line characters. Do you have any idea how I could also match for a word in front of a new line? I tried `[\s\S]` but this matches each line

Comment: @vinni It's often better to use multiple Regex rather than trying to build one that covers all cases. But you can try something like this : `value.find(/(.*\n){2}.+New York.+(\n.*){2}|(.+\n){2}.*New York(\n.*){2}/i).join('\n')` (note : I added a "i" at the end of the regex, so this one is case insensitive. It finds "New York" as well as "New york")

Comment: Ah, that's a good hint. Thanks! This seems to work: `(.*\n){2}(.+|)Kreuzberg(.+|)(\n.*){2}` Do you think there is an issue with that?

Comment: Ok, this is my final solution: `(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*(Kreuzberg).*)\n(.*)\n(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like completely avoiding RegEx and simply read the text and write the line before and the line after this is something you can get, if you write the text in Cell `A1` in Excel:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String
    inputString = Range("A1")

    Dim lookForWord As String
    lookForWord = "New York"

    Dim inputArr As Variant
    inputArr = Split(inputString, vbLf)

    Dim line As Variant
    Dim previousLine As String
    Dim foundWord As Boolean
    Dim linesAfter As Long: linesAfter = 1

    For Each line In inputArr
        If InStr(1, line, lookForWord) Then
            previousLine = previousLine & vbCrLf & line
            foundWord = True
        Else
            If foundWord And linesAfter Then
                previousLine = previousLine & vbCrLf & line
                linesAfter = linesAfter - 1
            ElseIf linesAfter Then
                previousLine = line
            End If
        End If
    Next line

    If Not linesAfter Then Debug.Print previousLine

End Sub
```

The `Split()` parses the text to an array like this:

[image]

the `linesAfter` variable can tell you how many lines after the word should be displayed.

Comment: Bro, he asked in OpenRefine, you come up with Excel. What's wrong with just sticking to openrefine ?

Comment: @iMitwe - nothing is wrong with sticking with openrefine. But the question is tagged with Excel as well, thus I come up with it.