# match multiline strings with regex

Tags: openrefine

Is it possible to match multiline strings with match() function?
I tried to apply match(/(abc)\rdef/) to a cell containing 2 lines of text abc & def, but it does not work. Is there a way to get "abc" as result?

Comment: From the link below, it should work with \n instead of \r !? Actually with a find() instead of a match()...<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758805/text-with-n-matching-in-regex-and-openrefine/50759334#50759334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `\n` (newline) instead of `\r` ([carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)).

```
value.match(/(abc)\ndef/)
```

[image]

But you have to indicate where the newline is. `match` has no "multliline" parameter, so the dot (`.`) doesn't match line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course ! Thanx Ettore

And I found a way to do what I wanted with `value.match(/(.*?\n)*(def)\n?(.*?\n?)*/)`

[image]